# Optimize code to get following output in c

Tags: c, optimization, time-complexity

I had an interview last week. They asked me to write a code to print like this

```
input :5
     0
    101
   21012
  3210123
 432101234
54321012345
```

i wrote the below code but he said i could optimize this more . i cant figure it out.
,

```
int main(){
  int n,i,j,k,lim,num;
  scanf("%d",&n);//getting input starting number of last row
  lim=n;
  int collen=n+2;//it denotes end of row 
  for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
  {
    num=i;
    k=0;
    for(j=0;j<collen-1;j++){
      if(j<lim)
        printf(" ");
      else if(num<0){
        
        printf("%d",++k);
      }
      else{
        printf("%d",num--);
        
      }
   }//j for
   printf("\n");
   collen++;
   lim--;
  }//i for
}// main end
```

I have different code at first attempt, I used flag to detect when num reaches for incrementing and decrementing, it was complex there was about 4 if inside second loop, so I optimized that code to the above one. He said can you optimize more? I have no idea to optimize it .

My question: can it be optimized? If it can be - please post the code

Comment: As soon as you wrote `scanf`, you failed the interview.  That is a command line parameter.

Comment: To my mind, there are inherently four loops here: (1) a loop from 0 up to 5, one for each row), (2) a loop to print spaces over to the start of a row, (3) a loop to print decrementing digits from the left edge of the triangle to the middle, and (4) a loop to print ascending digits from the middle to the right edge.  So if I see a solution with four loops, and maybe three variables (a "max" number, here 5, and two counters, since the loops are nested), that feels "just right".  You might be able to get away with "less" than that, but it will be at the cost of unnatural, increased complexity.

Comment: @SteveSummit you don't need a loop for digits, just use `char *digits = "0123456789";`  somewhere at the beginning.

Comment: We all don't know what the exact task was. How can you be sure about the requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There are more `for`-loops than those comparing by `<`. `for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)` is much clearer written as `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)`.
2. If you initialize a value, in example `int collen=n+2;`, and later use it like `collen-1`, save the subtraction and initialize it adjusted.
3. Separate this complex inner loop with `if`s into their own loops.
4. Use less variables.
5. Use more and consistent whitespace.

And now my solution, but as yours it can only handle inputs from 0 to 9:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;

    printf("input :");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 0 || n > 9) {
        printf("input not recognized or invalid\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
        printf("%*d", n - i + 1, i);
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
            printf("%d", j);
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            printf("%d", j);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks optimized to the brims:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    puts( "input :5");
    puts( "     0");
    puts( "    101");
    puts( "   21012");
    puts( "  3210123");
    puts( " 432101234");
    puts( "54321012345");
}
```

Comment: If you use `puts`, you don't need to include the `\n`, but with printf you really do need it.

Comment: no input is the number number to start print in last row

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar here it is!

Comment: .it only prints for input 5. it will not for other inputs like 6 , 2 numbers

Comment: You missed the chance to output just one string. -1

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
/* Print a pyramid */

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        int size = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1],NULL,10) : 5;
        if( size > 9 || size < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid size\n");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        for(int line = 0; line <= size; line++) {
                char template[]="9876543210123456789";
                char *s = template + 9 - size;
                template[10 + line] = '\0';
                memset(s, ' ', size - line);

                if(puts(s) == EOF) {
                        perror("puts");
                        return EXIT_FAILURE;
                }
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```